# Yii. CGridView in frontend. CActiveDataProvider without $model->search()

Tags: sorting, yii, frontend, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

I don't know if it is possible, but suppose it must be.
I need to present some data in frontend view - the list of companies in tabular form:
Company name 1 - Country 1 - Website 1 - etc...
Company name 2 - Country 2 - Website 2 - etc...
etc...
I'm trying to use CGridView for this purpose.

My controller:

```
public function actionList()
{

    $sort = new CSort();
    $sort->attributes = array(
        'defaultOrder'=>'company_name DESC',
        'company_name'=>array(
            'asc'=>'company_name ASC',
            'desc'=>'company_name DESC',
        ),
        'country'=>array(
            'asc'=>'country ASC',
            'desc'=>'country DESC',
        ),
    );

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->order = "company_name DESC";
    $criteria->condition = 'approve = :approve';
    $criteria->params = array(':approve'=>1);       

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('EuCompanies', array('criteria'=>$criteria,'sort'=>$sort));

    $this->render('list', 
    array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                                     ));
}
```

My view:

```
<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(                                                 
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,                                                             
      'columns'=>array(                                                                                                                                                                            
        'company_name',
        'country',
        'company_website',
        'economic_sector',
        'contact_person',
        'email',
        'phone_number'                                                                                                                                                                                  
      ),                                                                                                 
    ));
    ?>
```

The output is a nice grid, which takes into account the selection criteria, and clickable "Company name" and "Country", but clicking on them doesn't make the column sort. I guess it is because sort can't be done without using $model->search() in dataProvider, or I've just done something wrong?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/590/sort-and-filter-a-custom-or-composite-cgridview-column-that-may-even-contain-data-from-different-tables/ and http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8784-cgridview-sort-columns/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. Two points were wrong:

First:

```
$criteria->order = "company_name DESC";
```

was over-riding any other sort. After deleting this string, my columns become sortable.

Second (default sort didn't work):

Had to move

```
$sort->attributes = array(
    'defaultOrder'=>'company_name DESC',
```

from attributes to

```
$sort = new CSort();
    $sort->defaultOrder = 'company_name ASC';
    $sort->attributes = array(...
```

Work done, thank you :)